# How many elements are in the list which results after factor passing $201^7$ four times?

Tags: number-theory

> Given a list, a factor pass is defined to be a process in which each element in the list is replaced by a list of the original element’s positive divisors. For example, after factor passing the number $4$, one gets $1, 2, 4$. After two factor passes, $4$ becomes $1, 1,2, 1,2,4$. How many elements are in the list which results after factor passing $201^7$ four times?

Note that $201^7 = 3^7 \cdot 67^7$. After the first pass, there are $$\sum_{i \mid 201^7} i$$ elements in the list. After the second pass there are $$\sum_{i \mid 201^7}d(i)$$ where $d(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of a positive integer $n$. How can we find the number of elements in the list after four passes?

Comment: Can you solve the problemfor $3^7$ and $67^7$ (or in general $p^k$) separately?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can we do it for one prime?

Comment: Both are prime so I guess there are 8 factors of each, so 64 factors of both together on the first pass.

Comment: @user19405892 2 is prime is it not ? see the prime power example in the question.

Comment: The first pass is given by the matrix with numbers 1 to 8 across the top and 1 to 8 down the side and their products in the corresponding rows and columns. On the next pass the maximal element 8x8 generates the whole same matrix and the other numbers generate smaller matrices down to the unit top left which just generates itself.

Comment: For $2$ we have $3,6,10,15$. These appear to be of the form $\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: I think the 2nd pass gives you $8^29^2/4$

Comment: @RobertFrost: $\binom{8}{1}^2$ at the first pass, $\binom{9}{2}^2$ at the second pass, $\binom{10}{3}^2$ at the third pass and $\binom{11}{4}^2$ at the final pass seem to agree with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Let us state that a $4$-path in a $7\times 7$ grid is something of the form
$$ (a_0,b_0)\mapsto(a_1,b_1)\mapsto (a_2,b_2)\mapsto (a_3,b_3)\mapsto (a_4,b_4)=(7,7) $$
with $a_k,b_k\in[0,7]$ and $a_0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4$, $b_0\leq b_1\leq b_2\leq b_3\leq b_4$.

**Claim 1**. by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) there are $\binom{11}{4}^2$ $4$-paths.

**Claim 2**. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, $\binom{11}{4}^2=\color{red}{108900}$ is also the answer to the given question.

---

Can you see how a divisor of a divisor of a divisor of a divisor of $201^7$ is related with a $4$-path?
Notice that *to be a divisor of$\ldots$* is a transitive relation and every divisor of $201^{7}$ is of the form $3^{a}67^{b}$ with $(a,b)\in[0,7]^2$.

Can you prove **Claim 1** on your own?